# Image.onLoad scope in JavaScript class

Tags: javascript, oop

When loading an image inside a class in Javascript, how can I have the callback be a method of the class instead of a global one?

```
tc = new TestClass();

var TestClass = function(){


    var img = new Image();
    img.src = 'mars.png';
    img.onLoad = this.imagesHasLoaded(); //does not work, 
            //uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'imagesHasLoaded' ....js:28

            img.onLoad = imageLoaded(); //Works, logs yes, its loaded


    function imageLoaded(){

        console.log("yes, its loaded");
    }

    this.imagesHasLoaded = function(){

        console.log("loaded happened");
    }

    function isLoaded(){

        trace("loaded happened");
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

At the time you call `this.imagesHasLoaded();`, the function does not exist, yet.

I recommend you to define all functions first and afterwards calling the initialization parts. Finally you can return an object, that holds the public functions:

```
var TestClass = function (path) {
    var priv, publ;

    /*
     * PRIVATE
     */
    priv = {
        img: null,

        imageLoaded: function () {
            console.log("yes, its loaded");
        }
    };

    /*
     * PUBLIC
     */
    publ = {
        isLoaded: function () {
            trace("loaded happened");
        }
    };

    priv.img = new Image();
    priv.img.src = path;
    priv.img.onload = priv.imageLoaded;


    return publ;
};

var tc = TestClass('mars.png');
```

PS: `imageLoaded()` could been called, cause it's not been defined as variable (in your code). Additionally you did not set `img.onload` to simply the function, but you set the function's result: Be careful of using brackets when using a function as callback ;) !

Answer (score 0):

The issue you are seeing is that you have not yet defined this.imagesHasLoaded yet when you get to the line with the error.

Javascript is executed sequentially, and does not look ahead to create functions.

If you change your code to this it will work:

```
tc = new TestClass();

var TestClass = function(){
    var img = new Image();
    img.src = 'mars.png';

    this.imagesHasLoaded = function(){

        console.log("loaded happened");
    }

    function isLoaded(){

        trace("loaded happened");
    }

    img.onLoad = this.imagesHasLoaded;
}
```

Also note that I removed the parentheses after `this.imagesHasLoaded`.  This is because with the parentheses, you will call this.imagesHasLoaded immediately, and assign the result of that call as an event handler.  If you remove the parentheses, you are assigning the function as the event handler and it will be called only when the image has finished loading.